# Show that for every positive integer $n$ $ \phi^{n}(x)=\left(c+f(c)+f^{2}(c)+\ldots . .+f^{n-1}(c)\right)+f^{n}(x) $

Tags: induction, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a real-valued function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \quad \forall x, y \in$
$\boldsymbol{R} .$ Define a function $\phi$ by $\phi(x)=c+f(x), x \in \boldsymbol{R},$ where $c$ is a real constant. Show that for every positive integer $n$
$$
\phi^{n}(x)=\left(c+f(c)+f^{2}(c)+\ldots . .+f^{n-1}(c)\right)+f^{n}(x)
$$
where, for a real-valued function $g, \quad g^{n}(x)$ is defined by
$$
g^{0}(x)=0, g^{1}(x)=g(x), g^{k+1}(x)=g\left(g^{k}(x)\right)
$$

I have tried using Induction, but it seems lengthy.Anyother approach will greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You could use induction.

Comment: It will be of great help if u show the process other than induction! It seems lengthy

Comment: Well, it's about 2-3 rows to calculate $\phi(\phi^n(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Induction step:**
$$\begin{align*}\phi^{n+1}(x)&=\phi(\phi^n(x))\\&=c+f(\phi^n(x))\\
&=c+f(c+f(c)+f^2(c)+\cdots+f^{n-1}(c)+f^{n}(x))\\
&=c+f(c)+f^2(c)+f^3(c)+\cdots+f^n(c)+f^{n+1}(x).\end{align*}$$